# appending first 2 characters and last 2 characters from a single given string

Tags: python, string, append, character

> **`both_ends`**
>
> Given a string `s`,  return a string made of the first 2 and the last 2
>   chars  of the original string,  so `'banana'` gives `'bana'` However, 
>   if the string length is less than 2, return instead the empty string.

My code:

```
def both_ends(string):
    for item in string:
        if len(item) < 2:
            return ["empty"]
        else:
            (item [0])(item [1]).append(item (len(item)-1))(item (len(item) -2))


string=["jelly"]
both_ended=both_ends(string)
print both_ended
```

Error message:

```
  File "both_ends.py", line 18, in <module>
    both_ended=both_ends(string)
  File "both_ends.py", line 14, in both_ends
    (item [0])(item [1]).append(item (len(item)-1))(item (len(item) -2))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: What are you using to learn Python? Your use of `()` is... not Python.

Comment: `return ["empty"]` returns a list with one element (the string "empty"). I think you should just return a string with no content (=> `""`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using string slicing more simply:

```
def get_22(s):
    return s[:2]+s[-2:] if len(s) >=2 else ''

>>> print get_22("banana")
bana
>>> print get_22("tomato")
toto
>>> print get_22("abc")
abbc
```

Comment: yeah seriously. why would you downvote this? its works very well